# background image won't let me place cursor in text field

Tags: css, forms, background-image

I have an image in the background, which is behind my form.  As a result it won't let me place the cursor inside the text field.

https://jsfiddle.net/RE006/4rat11xc/1/

HTML:

```
<div id = "navButton">&#9776; Menu</div>

<div class="topnav" id="topNav">
<a href = "#" id= "closebtn">&times;</a>  
<a href=#>Home</a>
<a href="#">Drinks</a>
<a href="#">Food Menu</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div>
<header>
<h1>Header</h1> 
</header>

<div class= "container">

<main> 
<div id="cup"></div>

<form action="registration.html" method="get" name="registration_form" id="registration_form">

<label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
<span>*</span><br>

</form>

</main>

<!-- end .container --></div>
</div><!--end of pushDown id-->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
label, input, select {
margin: 10px 0px;
z-index: 9997;
}

/* cup image background */
#cup { 
background-image: url(images/cup.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
content:'';
filter: alpha(opacity=5); /* For IE8 and earlier */
height: 400px;
left: 20%;
opacity: 0.5;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
width: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RE006/4rat11xc/

Comment: `#cup { z-index: -1;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this specific issue in two ways:

```
#cup { z-index: -1; }
/* or */
#registration_form { position: relative; }
```

The reason this is happening is because the form is still `position: static`. Elements with position static are unaffected by positioning properties like `top` and `z-index`, so the other elements on the page that are not static are basically on a different "plan of existence" (there's probably a better technical term for this).

Changing `#cup` to be explicitly in the back will fix this. When you change the form to to `relative`, it moves into the same "plane of existence" as the non-static elements and therefore is stacked according to its position in the DOM (on top of `#cup`).

Comment: The #registration_form { position: relative; } works

Comment: The #registration_form { position: relative; } works
However if I use #cup { z-index: -1; }, the image does not show up.

For body: I use position: relative, so I am not sure why the form would be static position.

Comment: @user3006792 even though the body is `relative`, the form inside it is still static since that is the default (static within the body as a container). Z-index is surprisingly confusing. [MDN has a good article about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)